# PHP & MySQL hosted on a Windows IIS server

Tags: php, iis

I have PHP code snippets that work fine on an Apache (Linux) web server that I am trying to get running on a Windows IIS server but I am not having much luck.

Could this be to do with paths using forward slashes when Windows likes back slashes?

Hope you can help.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference between windows apache or linux apache but maybe the server configuration on linux you used to run your script differs from IIS configuration you must check both APACHE and PHP.INI in both servers maybe you need to enable something.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We do not have Apache installed on the IIS server, just PHP and MySQL and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be path issue but if will only help if you can show us some examples and errors what you are getting.

But, in black box, I can only let you know, check your script if there is any get_include_path function there and using hard code values `":"` to set path as it differs for windows which uses `";"` to include scripts, instead use PATH_SEPARATOR.

Check example here: http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html

But, it will surely help once you put results in your question.